# XML/C# - Como criar tags contendo outras tags dentro dela

Tags: c#, xml

Alá Pessoal estou com o seguinte problema: preciso criar um arquivo xml de produtos, no qual cada produto terá um grupo, até ai tudo bem, só ao adicionar os dados ele cria a tag de produto e dentro dela cria a de grupo, só ao criar o produto e ir adicionar o grupo ele sempre está fazendo da seguinte forma encontra a primeira tag de produto e adiciona todos os grupos. Então como eu faria para ele adicionar o grupo sempre para a última tag de produto.

Resultado esperado:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>    
-<fdv>    
<data>05/12/2012 17:41:08</data>    
<vendedor>V001</vendedor>   

-<valores>  

-<produto>    
<codigoImport>000083</codigoImport>    
<descricao>MAÇANETA GOL</descricao>    
<un>PÇ</un>    
<precoVenda>12.5</precoVenda>    
<estoque>180</estoque>    
<codBarras>00000833</codBarras>    
<url>http://user.img.todaoferta.uol.com.br/5/P/JO/NDEDP</url>    
<obs>Aplicado em veículo modelo: 2001 2002 2003</obs>    
-<grupo>    
<codigoImport>1001</codigoImport>    
<descricao>PORTAS</descricao>    
</grupo>    
</produto>   

-<produto>    
<codigoImport>000084</codigoImport>    
<descricao>MAÇANETA PALIO</descricao>    
<un>PÇ</un>    
<precoVenda>15</precoVenda>    
<estoque>200</estoque>    
<codBarras>00000840</codBarras>    
<url>http://www.takamineacessorios.com.br/prdfotos/prd_</url>    
<obs>Aplicados em modelos: 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010</obs> 

-<grupo>    
<codigoImport>1001</codigoImport>    
<descricao>PORTAS</descricao>    
</grupo>    
</produto>        
</valores>    
</fdv>
```

Esse é o meu código de acordo com o exemplo do Marco Antonio Quintal, agora como falei ele só estar criando o último registro:

```
#define Windows_Application
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;

namespace GSD
{
    class XmlProduto3
    {
        //Diretorio do arquivo Xml;
        private string diretorioArqXml()
        {
            string diretorio = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            string mensagem = String.Empty;
            string caminho = diretorio.Trim() + @"\XML\";

            if (!Directory.Exists(caminho))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(caminho);
            }
            return caminho;
        }

        //Cria o arquivo Xml;
        public void criarArqXml()
        {
            string caminho = diretorioArqXml() + "impprodutos.xml";
            string sqlFunCod = @"SELECT FUNCOD FROM SYS_USUARIO WHERE CODUSU = " + Engebuilder.Library.ConstEngebuilder.codUsu.ToString().Trim() + "";
            string funcod = Engebuilder.Library.LDataAccess.GetDataToString(sqlFunCod);
            Engebuilder.Library.LDataAccess.ExecuteCommand(sqlFunCod);

            ArrayList VlrProCod = new ArrayList();
            ArrayList VlrProDes = new ArrayList();
            ArrayList VlrProUni = new ArrayList();
            ArrayList VlrProPrc = new ArrayList();
            ArrayList VlrProEst = new ArrayList();
            ArrayList VlrProCodBar = new ArrayList();
            ArrayList VlrProCodGrp = new ArrayList();
            ArrayList VlrProDesGrp = new ArrayList();

            DataSet ds = Engebuilder.Library.LDataAccess.GetDataSet("SELECT "
            + " PRODUTO.PROCOD, "
            + " PRODUTO.PRODESRDZ, "
            + " PRODUTO.PROUNID, "
            + " PRODUTO.PROPRCVDAVAR, "
            + " ESTOQUE.ESTATU, "
            + " PRODUTOAUX.PROCODAUX, "
            + " PRODUTO.GRPCOD, "
            + " GRUPO.GRPDES "
            + " FROM PRODUTO "
            + " INNER JOIN ESTOQUE ON ESTOQUE.PROCOD = PRODUTO.PROCOD "
            + " LEFT JOIN PRODUTOAUX ON PRODUTOAUX.PROCOD = PRODUTO.PROCOD "
            + " LEFT JOIN GRUPO ON GRUPO.GRPCOD = PRODUTO.GRPCOD "
            + " ORDER BY PRODUTO.PROCOD");

            foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                VlrProCod.Add(row["PROCOD"].ToString().Trim());
                VlrProDes.Add(row["PRODESRDZ"].ToString().Trim());
                VlrProUni.Add(row["PROUNID"].ToString().Trim());
                VlrProPrc.Add(row["PROPRCVDAVAR"].ToString().Trim());
                VlrProEst.Add(row["ESTATU"].ToString().Trim());
                VlrProCodBar.Add(row["PROCODAUX"].ToString().Trim());
                VlrProCodGrp.Add(row["GRPCOD"].ToString().Trim());
                VlrProDesGrp.Add(row["GRPDES"].ToString().Trim());
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < VlrProCod.Count; i++)
            {
                XDocument doc = new XDocument(
                  new XElement("fdv",
                    new XElement("data", DateTime.Now.ToString()),
                    new XElement("vendedor", funcod),
                    new XElement("produto",
                      new XElement("codigoImport", VlrProCod[i].ToString()),
                      new XElement("descricao", VlrProDes[i].ToString()),
                      new XElement("un", VlrProUni[i].ToString()),
                      new XElement("precoVenda", VlrProPrc[i].ToString()),
                      new XElement("estoque", VlrProEst[i].ToString()),
                      new XElement("grupo",
                        new XElement("codigoImport", VlrProCodGrp[i].ToString()),
                        new XElement("descricao", VlrProDesGrp[i].ToString()
                  )
                )
              )
            )
          );

                doc.Save(caminho);
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Dados exportado com sucesso!", "Atenção!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seja bem vindo ao [pt.so], poste o código que você já fez, isso facilita que as pessoas te ajudem, veja [Como criar um exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável](/help/mcve), depois você também pode fazer um [tour] e conhecer como funciona o SOpt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você deverá usar a classe [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx)

Mais ou menos assim para criar os subníveis:

```
        new XElement("fdv",
            new XElement("vendedor", "V001"),
            new XElement("produto",
                new XElement("codigoImport", "000083"),
                new XElement("grupo",
                    new XElement("codigoImport", "1001")
                )
            )
        )
        .Save("produtos.xml");
```

Espero ter ajudado. Qualquer problema mande um comentário que respondo.

Complementando a resposta: depois que você adicionou mais codigo,
declare o `XDocument` e o elemento raiz fora do `for`, e adicione os outros elementos no `for`.

Comment: Olá, fiz como você sugeriu mas ainda estou com um problema, é que eu tenho uma lista de produtos, no os adiciono em um ArrayList e depois uso um FOR para a criação do XML, só que ele está apenas criando o último registro é como se ele estivesse sobrescrevendo os dados.

Comment: Declare o XDocument fora do for. Ex: XDocument doc;

Comment: Blz, já te envie o convite abaixo também coloquei o código anterior que estava fazendo e também o de acordo com o teu exemplo.

Comment: Mesmo assim tendo declarado ele fora do for ainda continuar só ficando o último registro.

Comment: Cara eu devo está com algum problema, rsrsrsrs. Já fiz refiz voltei ao anterior e nada, continuar tudo do mesmo jeito tanto em um como no outro.

Comment: @JoaquimCaetanoTeixeira, faça como o Marco falou, coloque o `XDocument` fora do `for`, algo assim `XDocument doc = new XDocument();`, ai dentro do `for` ao invés de criar um novo `XDocument`, você faz `doc.Add(new XElement("fdv", ...);` (os pontinhos representam o restante do código). Outro detalhe, utilize o `doc.Save(caminho);` fora do `for` também.

Answer (score 4):

É isso mesmo Pessoal, muito obrigado pelas as ajuda o código correto agora ficou desta forma:

```
#define Windows_Application
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using System.Management;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;

namespace GSD
{
    public class XmlProduto
    {
        public XmlProduto()
        {
        }   

        //Diretorio do arquivo Xml;
        private string diretorioArqXml()
        {
            string diretorio = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            string mensagem = String.Empty;
            string caminho = diretorio.Trim() + @"\XML\";

            if (!Directory.Exists(caminho))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(caminho);
            }
            return caminho;
        }

        //Cria o arquivo Xml;
        public void criarArqXml()
        {
            try
            {
                string caminho = diretorioArqXml() + "impprodutos.xml";

                string sqlFunCod = @"SELECT FUNCOD FROM SYS_USUARIO WHERE CODUSU = " + Engebuilder.Library.ConstEngebuilder.codUsu.ToString().Trim() + "";
                string funcod = Engebuilder.Library.LDataAccess.GetDataToString(sqlFunCod);
                Engebuilder.Library.LDataAccess.ExecuteCommand(sqlFunCod);

                string VlrProCod = String.Empty;
                string VlrProDes = String.Empty;
                string VlrProUni = String.Empty;
                string VlrProPrc = String.Empty;
                string VlrProEst = String.Empty;
                string VlrProCodBar = String.Empty;
                string VlrProCodGrp = String.Empty;
                string VlrProDesGrp = String.Empty;

                DataSet ds = Engebuilder.Library.LDataAccess.GetDataSet("SELECT "
                  + " PRODUTO.PROCOD, "
                  + " PRODUTO.PRODESRDZ, "
                  + " PRODUTO.PROUNID, "
                  + " PRODUTO.PROPRCVDAVAR, "
                  + " ESTOQUE.ESTATU, "
                  + " PRODUTOAUX.PROCODAUX, "
                  + " PRODUTO.GRPCOD, "
                  + " GRUPO.GRPDES "
                  + " FROM PRODUTO "
                  + " INNER JOIN ESTOQUE ON ESTOQUE.PROCOD = PRODUTO.PROCOD "
                  + " LEFT JOIN PRODUTOAUX ON PRODUTOAUX.PROCOD = PRODUTO.PROCOD "
                  + " INNER JOIN SECAO ON SECAO.SECCOD = PRODUTO.SECCOD "
                  + " INNER JOIN GRUPO ON (GRUPO.SECCOD = SECAO.SECCOD "
                  + " AND GRUPO.GRPCOD = PRODUTO.GRPCOD) "
                  + " INNER JOIN SUBGRUPO ON (SUBGRUPO.SECCOD = SECAO.SECCOD "
                  + " AND SUBGRUPO.GRPCOD = GRUPO.GRPCOD "
                  + " AND SUBGRUPO.SGRCOD = PRODUTO.SGRCOD) "
                  + " ORDER BY PRODUTO.PROCOD");


                //Verrifica se o arquivo existe, caso sim o deleta;
                if (File.Exists(caminho))
                {
                    File.Delete(caminho);
                }

                XElement doc = new XElement("fdv");

                doc.Add(new XElement("data", DateTime.Now.ToString()));
                doc.Add(new XElement("vendedor", funcod));
                XElement valores = new XElement("valores");

                foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    VlrProCod = row["PROCOD"].ToString().Trim();
                    VlrProDes = row["PRODESRDZ"].ToString().Trim();
                    VlrProUni = row["PROUNID"].ToString().Trim();
                    VlrProPrc = row["PROPRCVDAVAR"].ToString().Trim();
                    VlrProEst = row["ESTATU"].ToString().Trim();
                    VlrProCodBar = row["PROCODAUX"].ToString().Trim();
                    VlrProCodGrp = row["GRPCOD"].ToString().Trim();
                    VlrProDesGrp = row["GRPDES"].ToString().Trim();

                    valores.Add(new XElement("produto",
                      new XElement("codigoImport", VlrProCod),
                      new XElement("descricao", VlrProDes),
                      new XElement("un", VlrProUni),
                      new XElement("precoVenda", VlrProPrc),
                      new XElement("estoque", VlrProEst),
                      new XElement("codBarras", VlrProCodBar),
                      new XElement("url", null),
                      new XElement("obs", null),
                      new XElement("grupo",
                        new XElement("codigoImport", VlrProCodGrp),
                        new XElement("descricao", VlrProDesGrp)
                        )
                       )
                     );
                }

                doc.Add(valores);
                doc.Save(caminho);
                MessageBox.Show("Dados exportado com sucesso!", "Atenção!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                MessageBox.Show("Ocorreu um erro gerar o arquivo XML!", "Atenção!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
        }
    }
}
```